# Python ExchangeLib: Moving Folder of the item

Tags: python, exchange-server

I am using the [ExchangeLib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/exchangelib/) in Python. and wanted to move my email from A folder to B folder.

```
    # I logined the Exchange Server and took the items as below:
    all_items=account.inbox.all()
    # then wanted to move the folder as below:
    target_folder=account.inbox.get_folder_by_name("TCN")
    recentone = all_items[0]
    # then I wanted to move the folder to "TCN"
    recentone.folder=target_folder;
    recentone.save()
```

However, it's not working and I cannot find the solution at the moment.
Is there any other way to move the folder of the item?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've posted the question to the github and got the answer from the author as below:

You can't move items between folders like that :-) You need to use the move() method. See https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib#creating-updating-deleting-sending-and-moving

in short the following code works for moving folder

```
    recentone.move(to_folder=target_folder)
```